# Managing a Queue with Multiple, Asynchronous Calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, queue

I'm writing a queue in JavaScript that will be processed by several "servers" asynchronously. I'm concerned that two servers might retrieve the same item from the queue. It doesn't appear to be happening now, but I don't want to leave it to chance. From my knowledge, JavaScript is single-threaded; does that permit the assumption that even though there will be several requests at the same time, JavaScript uses it's own queue to execute the function?

```
function getJob() {
  if(jobs.length > 0) {
      var job = jobs.shift();
      $('#jobStatsQueueCount').text(jobs.length);
      return job;
  } else {
      return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yaB/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JavaScript is single-threaded; does that permit the assumption that even though there will be several requests at the same time

*"at the same time"* does not exist in computer land. There is always some order.

If you click twice you get two onclick events, one after the other. Even if your browser was busy while you clicked they will still happen one after the other, and in the same order you fired them. This is what you can assume: Events never race each other, overtake or interleave.

Since there is no event-interleaving you'll never run the risk of common threading bugs like the one you're suggesting, even if `shift` wasn't atomic (which it probably isn't, but it also doesn't matter).

Comment: True, but what about this scenario: there is one job; server 1 determines there is one job; server 2 determines there is one job, server 1 retrieves the job, then server 2, already past the check, fails because the job is gone.

Comment: ...or, are you saying that server 2's execution of getJob won't happen until server 1's execution is complete?

Comment: ...or, when you look at my full code, the interval event of any server won't execute until JavaScript finishes any interval event already executing.